# Remove all Ruby from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, ruby, ruby-on-rails, rvm, rubygems

I’m trying to start a new project with RadiantCMS, but I’m having lots of problems, because in the server are 2 different Ruby installations.

The first one, was installed [following this tutorial](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/install-rvm-ubuntu-1204-linux-for-ruby-193) and the second is via RVM.

Please, can somebody guide me to uninstall this the correct way.

Comment: The general approach is to identify where files are installed (or carefully record that at the time of installation) and remove them. Re-run the installers you used and save the output. I've heard some bad things about ruby deployment, and clearly there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can switch ruby versions with the following commands:

```
rvm install ruby_version
```

After the installation, we can list the available Ruby versions we have installed by typing:

```
rvm list
```

We can switch between the Ruby versions by typing:

```
rvm use ruby_version
```

We can use various Rails versions with each Ruby by creating gemsets and then installing Rails within those using the normal gem commands:

```
rvm gemset create gemset_name    # create a gemset
rvm ruby_version@gemset_name  # specify Ruby version and our new gemset
gem install rails -v rails_version   # install specific Rails version
```